# Ruby 省略記法の中身

Tags: ruby

省略記法を試していて

```
array１ = %w[あ　い　う]
array2 = ["あ","い","う"]
puts array == array2
```

を実行したら`false`が帰ってきました。
省略記法を使うと中身が変わってしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: array1に代入しているのに、比較ではarrayを使っているようですが、タイプミスでしょうか？

Comment: Rubyに詳しい方が解説して下さると思いますが、とりあえず「　」（全角スペース）が原因だと思います。「１」にも全角を、おそらく意図せず使用なさっているようですので、区別しやすいエディタやフォントの使用をお勧めします。

Comment: array１ = %w[あ い う] → array１ = %w(あ い う)では？

Comment: @miy 半角スペースに直したらTrueが返ってきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @nagao %記法は%`なんとか`に続く文字と対応する文字のペアであればなんでも構わないので、`(` & `)`でも`[` & `]`でも`{` & `}`でも結果は変わりません。`"`を使うと（エスケープなどで）煩雑なときの代替記法なので、自由度が比較的高いです。@Hibiki 解決して良かったです。stackoberflowでは自己回答が出来るので、解決出来た方法をご自身で回答し、今後同様の問題で躓いた方への参考になるようにご協力いただけるとより良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ruby (少なくとも MRI)では、構文上特殊な意味合いを持ちうる文字列は、すべて ASCII 文字である様子です。(下のリンクで定義される関数などを用いて、 parse.y は記述される)

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a8812080c4977c2731e8ff1b129b59d236bc12e3/include/ruby/ruby.h#L2220

その意味で、全角スペースはとくに構文的な意味を与えられているわけではなく、なのでひとつの文字列 `あ　い　う` として ruby の構文解析は動いていたと思われます。(なので、最終的に `array1` は `["あ　い　う"]` という長さ１の配列としてパースされた模様)

それ以外は、他の方が解説している通りです。

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 = %w[あ い う]
array2 = ["あ","い","う"]
puts array1==array2
#=>true
```

https://paiza.io/projects/IFZhiTCoZj-dFF_-crCK7A
となりました。